# Backing up VBA Project

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to backup my VBA project, but cant seem to find an easy solution.

I can export Each Userform and Module separately and then save that remotely. But was wondering if there wasnt another way?

I saw on another [website](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-backup-and-save-your-outlook-vba-macros/) about copying the Outlook VBA .OTM file. is this the same file extension as Word VBA?

Comment: Backup the folder where all your save files are?

Comment: The question is where are the sames files? See the updates question @phil

Comment: Normally in My Documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution was to export all my current Modules and Userforms and then import them into a a New Word Document, which I then saved as a Macro Enabled Template.

Now I just need to work out of the Template Project and not my Original Project.

Having the Template Project will also allow me to easily distribute my program to colleagues.

Answer (score 4):

#### Source Control.

That's how devs work worldwide, in pretty much every language out there. The Office-embedded nature of VBA complicates this a little, but it's a solved problem, with several solutions.

One of them is currently under active development, and adds a dockable side panel to your IDE, much like Visual Studio's *Team Explorer*:

[image: RD Source Control panel]

[**Rubberduck**](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com) is a COM add-in for the VBE, that includes this functionality - namely, Git/GitHub source control integration for your VBA projects.

It's a little bit of a "beta" feature in the latest version (1.4.3 as of this writing), but out of all other options, an IDE-integrated source control solution is certainly the best possible way to go about not only *backing up* your code, but also to get all the advantages of proper source control.

> **Disclaimer**: I haven't written the source control integration feature, but I co-own the Rubberduck project, which is free and open-source (i.e. I have no vested interest in advertising it).

Comment: so the Rubberduck add-in will allow be to export my project?

Comment: By creating a repository, yes.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen the only thing is that you need to rename your project if it's named `VBAProject1` - once a path is hooked up the add-in exports everything in the project to that folder. I suggest you download a Git client to help with the initial set-up - e.g. *GitHub for Windows*. Then the physical files will be updated everytime you commit changes.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Public Sub Test()

    ExportVBA ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Export\"

End Sub

Public Sub ExportVBA(sDestinationFolder As String)

    Dim oVBComponent As VBComponent

    For Each oVBComponent In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        oVBComponent.Export sDestinationFolder & oVBComponent.Name
    Next oVBComponent

End Sub
```

Just specify the destination folder and you're good to go

Comment: From the `ThisWorkBook` is assume your coding is for Excel? Im using Word. and it doestn seem to accept the Code